# Hibernate - Using Distinct Select query in Criteria

Tags: hibernate, select, distinct

Hope all of you are fine. Well I am quite new to all this Hibernate stuff and I am having a difficulty getting a Select Distinct query to work. The Query I'm trying to work is as follows,

```
Select Distinct user_type from Users
```

The users table has values as follows,

```
---------------------------------------
| user_id  |  user_name  | user_type  |
---------------------------------------
|    1     | mark taylor | admin      |
|    2     | bill paxton |co-ordinator|
|    3     | tony brooks | admin      |
|    4     | ali jahan   | developer  |
---------------------------------------
```

The result I'm expecting at the end of the query is,

```
admin,co-ordinator,developer
```

What I'm hoping to get is a list of user_types as a return statement, the function i've written after searching for help is as follows,

```
public List<User> findDistinctUserType() throws HibernateException {
    Criteria c = this.createCriteria();
    c.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("user_type")));
    return (List<User>) (User) c.uniqueResult();
}
```

I've looked at another example and tried this as well,

```
public List<User> findDistinctUserType() throws HibernateException {
    Criteria c = this.createCriteria();
    ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
    ProjectionList projectionList2 = Projections.projectionList();

    projectionList2.add(Projections.distinct(projectionList
            .add(Projections.property("user_type"),"user_type")));

    c.setProjection(projectionList2);
    c.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class));

    return (List<User>) (User) c.uniqueResult();
}
```

But for odd reason, it's always failing and I'm not getting through, if you could please provide me with a good solution, that'll be great. Looking forward to your help.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

The output I am expecting is as follows,

```
admin,co-ordinator,developer
```

What I am currently getting without this code is,

```
admin,co-ordinator,admin,developer
```

The above mentioned function is called in the following manner,

```
List<User> userList = userDao.findDistinctUserType();
```

User is an object which contains the following information,

```
private int id;
private String userName;
private String userType;
```

further down the code we have where User object is defined, we have,

```
@Column(name="user_type", nullable=false)
public String getUserType() {
    return userType;
}
```

Comment: If you go to a store and ask for screwdrivers, you'll get screwdrivers, not whole toolboxes. Similarly, if you select user types, what you'll get is user types. Not users. If you want users, then select users: `select [distinct] u from User u`.

Comment: I am looking for the query to return only user_type, user_type is part of the User object. User object defines the following,
`private int id;`
`private String userName;`
`private String userType;`
With further down the code I have this, 
`@Column(name="user_type", nullable=false)`
`public String getUserType(){ return userType;}`

Comment: What error(s) do you get? Also please put the information on the question itself not in the comments.

Comment: Okay Ean, I have edited my question above.

Comment: How does `return (List<User>) (User) c.uniqueResult();` work? Two casts doesn't even compile. In addition `Projections.property("user_type")` should be `Projections.property("userType")`.

Comment: Your query won't return users. It will return a List<String>, since you asked for user types, and userType is of type String.

Comment: @Ean While working on Netbeans, it proposed double casting and it compiles and doesn't even return an error.

Comment: @JBNizet I think I have to rephrase over here, all I need is a distinct list of user_types, I don't need to get the user_name or id, only the return should be a discreet list of user_types, exactly when you run the SQL query, select discreet user_types from users. What you get as a result,that I want my function to return, the codes I've put above are the ones I found over the internet and tried those but nothing helped, hence asking someone to help me here lol :),hope now my Question is clear

Comment: several questions here...1. if you want a list of sth, use `c.list()`, `uniqueResult()` is used when you expect a single result, either unique, or some objects that are equivalent returned as one. 2. you might wanna use List<String> as the type, since userType is string. 3. use `userType` instead of `user_type`

Comment: The HQL query `select distinct u.userType from User u` will return you a List<String>, containing the user types. I don't understand why your method returns a List<User>, since you just said that this is not what you wanted. A list of user types is a List<String>, not a List<User>. A List<User> contains users, not user types.

Comment: Gotcha!!! I'll give the suggestions a go ... u know how it is when a complete illiterate tries to start something new lol !!! Thanks guys ... I'll update you once I've given them a try :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you all for all your feedback, I was able to solve the problem. As per your suggestion, I did this and this worked for me,

```
public List<String> findDistinctUserName() throws HibernateException {
    List<String> returnVal = new ArrayList<String>();

    Criteria c = this.createCriteria();
    c.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("userType")));
    c.addOrder(Order.asc("userType"));

    List<String> userTypeList = c.list();

    for(String userType : userTypeList) {
        if(!userType.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            returnVal.add(userType);
        }
    }

    return returnVal;
}
```

Thanks for all your answers. Be ready I might be asking more as I go along lol !!!

Comment: It does work, but not a proper solution. There should be no "for" loop after the c.list();